# Show that $\sum_{k=2}^\infty d_k$ converges to $\lim_{n\to\infty} s_{nn}$.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

I've included some relevant information below:

[image: theorem]
So far I've managed to show that $\sum_{k=2}^\infty |d_k|$ converges, but I don't know how to move on from there.